# How to add/subtract element values in ng-repeat in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="isExpanded" ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <div class="colA">Account</div>
                <div class="colB">Kilometer</div>
                <div class="colA">Net</div>
                <div class="colC">61</div>
                <div class="colA">Vat</div>
                <div class="colC">V2</div>
                <div class="colA">Row Total</div>
                <div class="colC">76</div>
            </div>

<div class="row" ng-show="isExpanded" ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <div class="colA">Account</div>
                <div class="colB">Diners</div>
                <div class="colA">Net</div>
                <div class="colC">5</div>
                <div class="colA">Vat</div>
                <div class="colC">V2</div>
                <div class="colA">Row Total</div>
                <div class="colC">5</div>
            </div>

<div class="row" ng-show="isExpanded" ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <div class="colA">Account</div>
                <div class="colB">Repairs</div>
                <div class="colA">Net</div>
                <div class="colC">6</div>
                <div class="colA">Vat</div>
                <div class="colC">V2</div>
                <div class="colA">Row Total</div>
                <div class="colC">7</div>
            </div>
```

I wish to add Row total in all the ng-repeat = row in rows
I can get row_total value in the following way:

```
element.all(by.repeater('row in rows')).count().then(function(count)
{

    for(i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {

        row_total = element(by.repeater('row in rows').row(i)).then(function(elem)
        {
            row_elem = elem.element(by.css('div:nth-child(8)'));
            return row_elem.getText();

        });


    }

});
```

Task to do: Find a way to add all these values and return the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following snippet should work for you

```
element.all(by.repeater('row in rows'))
  .then(function (rows) { 
    var sum = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
      rows[i].element(by.css('div:nth-child(8)')).getText()
        .then(function (row_total) { 
          sum += parseFloat(row_total); 
        }); 
     } 
     expect(sum).toEqual(42); 
});
```

edit: i updated my answer for better code formatting

Comment: for(row in rows) return 0,1.. etc for row! There is probly some other way to access the repeaters

Comment: @SakshiSingla you are right, i am sorry - untested as i said. i edited my question: replaced for(x in y) with array.forEach loop

Comment: I tried the following way:  
element.all(by.repeater('row in rows')).then(function(rows) {
    var sum = 0;
 
    for(i=0 ; i<rows.length; i++) {

 a_row_total = rows[i].element(by.css('div:nth-child(8)')).getText().then(function(row_total)
 {
  
  return parseFloat(row_total);
 });
 
      sum += a_row_total; // add your locator for child elements
   
    }
    expect(sum).toEqual(42); // expect your value
});
a_row_total is a PROMISE whereas sum is a normal variable
So, error:  Expected '0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]' to equal 42

Comment: do you _need_ `a_row_total` to be a promise? then i maybe didn't got your question right ... if not, how about this: `element.all(by.repeater('row in rows')).then(function (rows) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].element(by.css('div:nth-child(8)')).getText().then(function (row_total) {
        sum += parseFloat(row_total);
      });
    }
    expect(sum).toEqual(42);
  });`